# bat file to launch exe and wait for string in standard output

Tags: windows, batch-file

Folks,

Is it possible to create a bat file that launches an executable and waits for a pre-determined string in the standard output.  When that string is found, the batch file will exit (the exe can continue running). How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

Note that originally MS-DOS was an operating system in which Windows ran.  Now it is an application that simulates the earlier OS.  The way to solve your would possibly involve using an application called from within MS-DOS, that will perform this kind of logic (i.e. IF(file_is_present_with_string)THEN {...}) in the MS-DOS command library.

Powershell is a powerful scripting language allowing you to perform many operations previously unavailable in MS-DOS, such as take the output from one MS-DOS command (e.g. ipconfig /all) and reformat it into a different layout, possibly using it as another command's input parameters (e.g. select a value from ipconfig and use it in another command).  Although it supports MS-DOS command execution, it does so through the use of  CMDLETs (pronouned command-let) which is a self-contained application designed to run inside Powershell. There are many other CMDLETs out there that might be able to help solve your problem.